# Dirichlet characters - proof in a book

Tags: analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I found the following in a book and don't understand. Let $\chi$ denote a non-principal character modulo $q$ and $S(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\chi (n)$. Then

$\sum_{m>y} \frac{\chi(m)}{m} = \int_y^{\infty }u^{-1}dS(u)=-\frac{S(y)}{y} + \int_y^{\infty }S(u)u^{-2}du$

What does "$dS(u)$" mean?

Comment: I'm not 100 per cent, but probably this is a [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

Answer (score 1):

In Apostol's book on analytic number theory this is Abel's identity applied to the function $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{x<m\le y}\frac{\chi(m)}{m}=\frac{S(y)}{y}-\frac{S(x)}{x}+\int_x^y \frac{S(t)}{t^2}dt,
$$
which gives for $y\to \infty$ the result
$$
\sum_{m\le x} \frac{\chi(m)}{m}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\chi(m)}{m}+O(1/x).
$$
Here the integral is the usual Riemann integral, but I also think that yours is the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, as Jyrki said. If you tell us which book you mean, then one could verify this of course.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right with the Stieltjes integral - it's the book of Montgomery and Vaughan: Multiplicative Number Theory, proof of Theorem 4.11 in the middle of page 125. I want to solve exercise 2. b)-d) are no problem, but I don't know how to solve exercise 2a), so my idea was to do the same as they did in this proof.

Comment: Now I have two questions to Apostol's method: Why goes $S(y)/y$ to $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{\chi (m)}{m}$ and why is the integral $O(1/x)$?

Comment: and is it right that you made a typo in your second equation? Should that be $m>x$?

Comment: No, it is $m\le x$, but the difference of the two series is then with index $m=1,...,\infty$ minus $m\le x$ equal to $m>x$.

Comment: You can solve exercise 2 a) with Abel summation applied to $f(t)=1/\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Ok, then I get $\sum_{n>x}\frac{\chi (n)}{\sqrt(n)} = L(1/2,\chi ) - \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\chi (n)}{\sqrt (n)}$ and the last term is with Abel summation $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{m\leq x}\chi (m) - \chi (1) + \frac{1}{2}\int_1^x \sum_{m\leq t}\chi (m) t^{-3/2} dt$. But the first summand is $O_{\chi }(1/x)$, so what's wrong?

Comment: problem solved - thank you!